Error Delete Distributor on sql Server 2019
I can't delete Distributor. The system shoew message error "Could not drop the Distributor  'Dis_name'. This Distributor has associated distribution database"

have you checked the official doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/mssql-eng014121?view=sql-server-ver16

Yes,  I tried to follow the documents it but can't delete.

and the output of this sp sp_helpdistpublisher is?

I has run  EXEC sp_helpdistpublisher ,  the system show output as follows :
security_mode = 0
active = 1
trusted = 0
thirdpatry_flag = 0
storage_connection_string = NULL

If you look at the distribution_db column you fill find what is the name of distribution db that is active and has do be removed before dropping the distributor.
